# How to transform dict in list with JavaScript to return in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, logic

My JSON return this:

```
[{"label": "Yes", "value": 26}, {"label": "No", "value": 21}]
```

I need this, in data.js to highcharts graphic.

```
[["Yes", 26], ["No", 21]]
```

A list inner list.

I try:

```
var paid_data = new Array();
var paid_data2 = new Array();

$.getJSON(url, function(res){
    console.log(res);
    // Transform dict to list
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        paid_data.push(res[i]['label'],res[i]['value']);
    };
    // List inner list
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        paid_data2.push(paid_data[i]);
        paid_data2.push(paid_data[i+1]);
    }
    console.log(paid_data);
```

**But not return this result:**

```
[["Yes", 26], ["No", 21]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Using ES6's [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
obj.map(el => [el.label, el.value]);
```

```js
var obj = [{"label": "Yes", "value": 26}, {"label": "No", "value": 21}];
var newObj = obj.map(el => [el.label, el.value]);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newObj, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Same code in ES5

```
obj.map(function (el) {
    return [el.label, el.value]
});
```

```js
var obj = [{
    "label": "Yes",
    "value": 26
}, {
    "label": "No",
    "value": 21
}];

var newObj = obj.map(function (el) {
    return [el.label, el.value]
});

console.log(newObj);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newObj, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```